# Android ACRA SphreadSheet link

Tags: android, google-sheets, crash-reports, acra

Hi
 i need to use ACRA for crashreporting , am using my company email account provided by google, the problem ACRA send crashreport to " Connect to http://spreadsheets.google.com/formResponse?... " in my case my sphreadsheet link contain my company name also how can use ACRA in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [issue open on the ACRA project issue tracker.](http://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=28)
Please star the issue to receive e-mails about its resolution.

EDIT:

You should only have to uncheck the option "Require yourdomain.com sign-in to view this form" on the form edition page. Then you just have to provide the formId to ACRA, no need to override the formUri.

Comment: Answer edited with the solution found by an ACRA user cf. http://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=28